# VBA checking if a row in a sheet contains multiple variables

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem looping through a sheet to find a row matching some variables.

I've got 8 columns per row, and I want to find a row that contains 6 variables, one empty cell and one cell with value 0. Like this:

```
- | A  | B  | C  | D  | E  | F  | G  | H  |
i | x1 |    | x2 | 0  | x3 | x4 | x5 | x6 |
```

Where `i` is a row number and `x1`, `x2`,.. `x6` are variables obtained from a CSV file. I want to check if my 'list' of variables `{x1, ,x2,0,x3,x4,x5,x6}` is an existing row in a sheet. So I want the program to do something `If (Ai = x1 And Bi = "" And Ci = x2 And Di = "0" And Ei = x3 And Fi = x4 And Gi = x5 And Hi = x6)` and do nothing when `Else`.

So I need to loop through all the rows and check if all variables are in 1 row.

At the moment I tried this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
LastCol = 8
LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Boekingen AMS-IAD").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LastRow
    For j = 1 To LastCol
        'Tried with only 1 criteria, still didn't work
        If (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Boekingen AMS-IAD").Cells(i, j).Value = x1) Then
            Accept = "nvt"
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: Do they have to be in that order, or do you want to check if a row contains them all in any order?

Comment: How doesn't it work? Do you get an error? FYI you should *always* qualify ranges, so change your line to: `LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Boekingen AMS-IAD").Range("A" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Boekingen AMS-IAD").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: GSerg yes they have to be in that order.
I don't get an error, it just doesn't give the output "nvt" for Accept while it should do that. Especially now I only have 1 of the 8 criteria, where I'm sure there is more than 1 row that contains the value of the variable x1.

Comment: How do you know it does not give the output, and what is `Accept` in the first place?

Comment: Because im 'printing' the output in an Excel sheet. Accept is a variable that will either get "Yes", "No" or "nvt" as a value. The piece of code I listed here is one of many 'Else If's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue, the problem wasn't in looping through the sheet, but in a value of a variable. The date was changed from D-M-Y to M-D-Y when I read it from the Excel sheet. But I fixed that, for the ones that are interested in the answer: [VBA changes date format from D-M-Y to M-D-Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637716/vba-changes-date-format-from-d-m-y-to-m-d-y?noredirect=1#comment70475555_41637716)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. I left everything pretty much as you had it with a couple of exceptions.

```
lastcol = 8

Dim vars

ReDim vars(1 To lastcol)

'Set vars() to the values you're looking for in the columns.

    LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Boekingen AMS-IAD").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        accept = ""
        met = 0
        For j = 1 To lastcol
            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Boekingen AMS-IAD").Cells(i, j)
            If .Value = vars(j) Then
                met = met + 1
            End If
            End With
        Next j
        If met = lastcol Then accept = "nvt"
        'At this point you have to do something with the row you just
        ' found--maybe leave the loop and do something, or do something
        ' before going to the next row.
    Next i
```

Comment: How do I Set vars() to the desired values? The values are (x1,"",x2,"0",x3,x4,x5,x6), the second value is supposed to be an empty cell.

Comment: If x1, etc., are actual VBA variables, you can just assign them, as in `vars(1) = x1` and so on. `vars(2) = ""` and `vars(4) = 0` The code is general below that--it will handle whatever number of checks you want, but at some point you have to initialize the values by hand or have an external source of values.

Comment: It gives me empty values ("") for Accept now. So until "accept = """ it's working, but the loop still doesn't seem to work. I haven't put anything yet after "If met = lastcol Then accept = "nvt"". Do you think that is the problem? If so, what should I try to put there?

Comment: Sorry to be offline so long. I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, so I don't know what you're really trying to do. My instinct says you have to do put your code to handle the "nvt" cases where my comment is. Otherwise, it will just go on to check the next row without doing anything with the current one. Something like `if accept = "nvt" then msgbox "Found one at row " & i`

Answer (score 0):

I made this quick little test sub in a new excel folder, renamed `Sheet1` to your sheet's name and it works excellently:

```
Sub testing()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Boekingen AMS-IAD")
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = x1 And _
        ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = "" And _
        ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = x2 And _
        ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = "0" And _
        ws.Cells(i, 5).Value = x3 And _
        ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = x4 And _
        ws.Cells(i, 7).Value = x5 And _
        ws.Cells(i, 8).Value = x6 Then
            'MsgBox "nvt at row " & i
            Accept = "nvt"
        End If
    Next i


End Sub
```

This should spit out "nvt" when the line follows your variables :)

PS - anyone looking to test this code, you just need to add the following under `Dim rng as Range`:

```
    Dim x1 As Integer
    Dim x2 As Integer
    Dim x3 As Integer
    Dim x4 As Integer
    Dim x5 As Integer
    Dim x6 As Integer

    x1 = 1
    x2 = 1
    x3 = 1
    x4 = 1
    x5 = 1
    x6 = 1
```

Comment: This gives me an error at "For each rng in ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)". Error 1004 while executing: Method Range of object_Worksheet has failed. The error could be formulated slightly different because my Excel isn't in English.

Comment: @Stan Thanks for the heads up! I've updated my answer to using `.Cells` like you are, hopefully this helps :)

Comment: No errors now, but still no result with "nvt". I feel like the loop works but there is something wrong with the values maybe? When I set LastCol to 1 and only put down "If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = x1" it still won't find anything, while there are more than 1 rows containing the value of x1 in their first column. If I change "If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = x1" to "If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = "4-sep-16"" it still won't find anything. ("4-sep-16" is the value of x1)

Comment: @Stan Thanks for the additional info. Have you tried changing the `Accept = "nvm"` to something like `Msgbox "One found here"`? The problem may be with your printing of the accept statement, could you edit your question to show how it is printed to the worksheet?  Also is Accept getting changed anywhere else after this section of the code?

Comment: Yes I put down a Msgbox under the line Accept = "nvm" but it wouldn't show a Msgbox either. The program exist of multiple If and Else If's, the ones where Accept = "Yes" are working fine and are printing "Yes" as they should. The Else If with "nvm" is the one I posted here. After this one I only have an Else that gives Accept = "No" and prints it perfectly too. So the printing works fine.