# Date format changes from D-M-Y to M-D-Y

Tags: excel, vba

Out of a csv file, I obtain a variable `BookingDate` with value "8-9-2016". I want to loop through an Excel sheet to check, if there is a match with that value.

I discovered, that the values I read from the sheet are changed, when I want to use them in VBA. Let's say, I set a variable `BookingDate2` and give it a value like this:

```
LR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheetname").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LR
    BookingDate2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Boekingen AMS-IAD").Cells(i, 1).Value
```

Then I want to check, if it found a match like this:

```
If (BookingDate = BookingDate2) Then
    'Do something
```

`BookingDate` has value "8-9-2016" and the value of `BookingDate2` is supposed to be "8-9-2016", but is changed to "9-8-2016".

Comment: Looking forward to a definitive answer on this, for me a triage is to store your dates with the month as 3 letters Jan/Feb... that way there is never confusion as to what the month is but this does not work for foreign languages.  Some smart guy should weigh in and give good answer referencing default locales etc.

Comment: The same question was asked 14 hours ago... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41625705/vba-is-changing-my-dates-to-mm-dd-yyyy-hhmm-when-importing/41632336

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed it!

I forgot to Dim the variables to Date.
It was like this:

```
Dim BookingDate As String
Dim BookingDate2 As String
```

But it had to be:

```
Dim BookingDate As Date
Dim BookingDate2 As Date
```

That did the trick for me.

Comment: Rule #1 (they're all #1, right?): always treat dates as *dates*!

Answer (score 0):

If you know for certain that `BookingDate2` always has the format of "d-m-y" and you want it to be "m-d-y", one approach is to split the date value, invert the order, and then save it back to the variable with the correct format before testing their values. Try this:

```
LR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheetname").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LR
    BookingDate2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Boekingen AMS-IAD").Cells(i, 1).Value
    Dim aux
    aux = Split(BookingDate2,"-")
    BookingDate2 = aux(1) & "-" & aux(0) & "-" & aux(2) 'reordering the date in the desired format

    If (BookingDate = BookingDate2) Then
        'Do something
```

This is, of course, assuming the date formats in both your CSV and your spreadsheet does not change